# "\\" in strings, passing string is only returning characters before first back slash

Tags: c#, string, itext

I'm trying to delete layers in a pdf using itextsharp. I have the method to delete a layer, however I only want to delete certain layers by name. The names have "\" in them ("þÿ\0E\0N"), I'm not getting the expected string.

```
Dictionary<string, PdfLayer> layers = stamp.GetPdfLayers();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PdfLayer> layer in layers)
{
    string layername = layer.Key.ToString();
}
```

but `layername` is coming out just as "þÿ" I don't know why it's ditching the rest of the string after the first "\".

Comment: `\0` is a NUL character, often (but not in .Net) used to signal the end of a string-value

Comment: Just to be clear, what is the length of your sample string: 6 or 8? In other words: is it really a backslash + zero, or a representation of the NUL character?

Comment: _unrelated:_ `layer.Key` is already a string ... why `layer.Key..ToString()`

Comment: its a backslash followed by a 0

Comment: its been put Tostring() because I've been trying for about 2 days to get it to work.

Comment: So is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure the `Key` has the `\0` characters in?

Comment: `\0` aren't two characters namely \ and 0 it is only one character as was already pointed out it is the `NUL` character. The leading \ is the escaping of `0`, a more common character is `\t` which escapes the `t` to represent a `tab` or `\n` which represents a new-line

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZYQVvE

Comment: Internally iText unfortunately retrieves the string from the `PdfString` object holding the layer name using `PdfString.ToString` and not `PdfString.ToUnicodeString()`. Thus, in case of UTF-16 encoded PDF strings you get one character per _byte_ of the UTF-16 PDF string, i.e. pretty often a NUL character and then an ANSI'ish character in case of Western languages, with a leading byte order mark. Furthermore, in PDF strings individual bytes may be escaped, e.g. a NULL byte may be written using two bytes `\0`. So here iText returns you something ugly...

Comment: @RandRandom *"`\0` aren't two characters namely \ and 0 it is only one character as was already pointed out it is the `NUL` character."* - Not necessarily. As described in the previous comment, PDF internal strings may be escaped byte-wise (even if they eventually are to be interpreted as double-byte characters), so an UTF-16 'A' may be stored as the byte sequence 0x5C 0x30 0x41 - "\0A" but it may also be stored as 0x00 0x41...

Comment: @Greg *'but `layername` is coming out just as "þÿ"'* - Coming out **where**?

Comment: @mkl in  string layername.

Comment: Can you share a PDF for which that happens?

Comment: I can't really share the pdf, it's not mine to share. Thanks for your help anyway.